# Can't align elements vertically with CSS

Tags: html, css

I know it is an ancient question but none of the existing solution worked for me.

I want to vertically align #name_post & #pic_post in center.

This is my code. If you run the code snippet you will see that I failed.

```css
.circular {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.heading_post{
 display; table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
.heading_name
{
 color: #45619d;
}
#pic_post, #name_post{
 display:inline;
}
#name_post_name, #name_post_work{
 display:inline;
}

.name{
 background-color: #dedfe1;
 border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 -o-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <li class="item">
             <div class= "name">
              <img id="pic_post" class="circular" src="http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/android_small.png" alt="" />
              <div id="name_post" class= "heading_post">
               <h5 id="name_post_name" class="heading_name">Tamzeed Islam</h5>
               <h5 id="name_post_work">posted on web</h5>
              </div>
             </div>
              <p id="post_details" class="details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. Duis cursus, mi quis viverra ornare, eros dolor interdum nulla, ut commodo diam libero vitae erat.</p>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See this solution:
only one change #pic_post, #name_post{vertical-align: middle;}**

```css
.circular {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.heading_post{
 display; table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
.heading_name
{
 color: #45619d;
}
#pic_post, #name_post{
 display:inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#name_post_name, #name_post_work{
 display:inline;
}

.name{
 background-color: #dedfe1;
 border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 -webkit-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 -o-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 -moz-border-radius:15px 15px 15px 15px;
 margin: 0px;
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <li class="item">
             <div class= "name">
              <img id="pic_post" class="circular" src="http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/android_small.png" alt="" />
              <div id="name_post" class= "heading_post">
               <h5 id="name_post_name" class="heading_name">Tamzeed Islam</h5>
               <h5 id="name_post_work">posted on web</h5>
              </div>
             </div>
              <p id="post_details" class="details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. Duis cursus, mi quis viverra ornare, eros dolor interdum nulla, ut commodo diam libero vitae erat.</p>
            </li>
```

Comment: but you can add one property to align this mention in top of code  #pic_post, #name_post{vertical-align: middle;}

Comment: Thanks a lot it did the trick. I can't thank you enough. @ Jenti Dabhi

Answer (score 2):

Add `text-align: center;` to the parent `.name`, then to `#pic_post, #name_post` add `vertical-align: middle;`.

```css
.item{list-style: none}
.circular {
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
 -moz-border-radius: 15px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.heading_post{
 display; table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
.heading_name
{
 color: #45619d;
}
.name {
background-color: #dedfe1;
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
-o-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
margin: 0px;
display: table;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}

#pic_post, #name_post {
vertical-align: middle;
display: inline;
}
#name_post_name, #name_post_work{
 display:inline;
}
```

```html
<li class="item">
    <div class= "name">
        <img id="pic_post" class="circular" src="http://cdn.makeuseof.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/android_small.png" alt="" />
        <div id="name_post" class= "heading_post">
            <h5 id="name_post_name" class="heading_name">Tamzeed Islam</h5>
            <h5 id="name_post_work">posted on web</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p id="post_details" class="details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse varius enim in eros elementum tristique. Duis cursus, mi quis viverra ornare, eros dolor interdum nulla, ut commodo diam libero vitae erat.</p>
</li>
```

Comment: Actually adding `vertical-align: middle;` to the `#pic_post` did the trick. The OP wants to align that elements vertically, not horizontally.

Comment: @HashemQolami well the remove `display:inline;` from `#name_post_name, #name_post_work`  http://jsfiddle.net/shcx7f5g/